# {Web} Flutter favicon can't be loaded in release mode

Tags: flutter-web

I just run in release mode but `favicon` is not loaded.
In debug mode, it's loaded fine.
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is still unreleased for the `web` target for flutter.
A recent merge to `master` branch shows the addition of functionality that copies the `web/*` files to the `build/web/` output directory.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/48316 - specifically this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/48316/files#diff-6edde590c56c73e35381fb97d37eb862R247-R260

So expect to see that in a near release!

Comment: Thank you! I'll wait for that:)